# Why is there a + sign always before eventhandlers?

Tags: c#, event-handling

In C# we attach an event handler like this:

```
form1.Click += new EventHandler(form1_Click);
```

What is the significance of the "plus" sign? **I know we can attach many eventhandlers for a control and hence the `+=` syntax makes sense**. But I think I should also be able to write just this:

```
form1.Click = new EventHandler(form1_Click);
```

so that i can override all the previous handlers and attach only the last one, but that wouldnt compile. Naturally I think `+=` operator should work as if it is for strings and ints. What is the design principle for **forcing** `+=` for handlers? **In other words why cant i write just `=` ?**

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a multicast delegate, which will give you the ability to add, remove and clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx) article, please, have a look at *Publishing and Subscribing* section.

> In C#, any object can publish a set of events to which other classes
>   can subscribe. When the publishing class raises an event, all the
>   subscribed classes are notified.

So, you are a subscriber, you are not concerned to influence the list of those, who has already subscribed. It's in the *publishers* competence.

If you say *it's up to a programmer*, than you could develop your "publisher"-classes so that they could provide some public method, giving an opportunity to any subscriber to reset some event subscription. In the framework it is prohibited by design. This is also a decision by certain programmers.

Comment: It would also introduce subtle programming bugs to make `=` available to outside consumers -- they could inadvertently wipe out all other event handlers and not notice it until much later.

Answer (score 4):

Event handlers are represented internally by an array of delegates so the normal `+=` & `-=` operators apply.

You can, however, use direct assigned with the `=`, but only within the class that defines the event, and this will wipe out all previous event handlers replacing with the one you're assigning.

Comment: That makes sense. Since I am not thorough with delegates, I am not clear. Do you mean delegates can only be represented by `+=` and `-=` ?

Comment: @nawfal - No, they are internally just an array of delegates (pointers) to the methods they represent. Since they are an array the `+=` & `-=` operators make sense for adding and removing delegates from the internal array.

Comment: Hmm, I get it. But I am wondering why C# was designed so in the first place. Anyway thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Its like

```
a += 2
```

that means

```
a = a + 2
```

if we did

```
a = 2
```

That would wipe out a value and replace it with 2.

similarly

```
form1.Click += new EventHandler(form1_Click);
```

means

```
form1.Click = form1.Click +  new EventHandler(form1_Click);
```

Means add our eventhandler to what form1.click was doing earlier.

Now form1.Click will do what it does by default and also do what we want it to do in form1_click

If we wrote

```
form1.Click = new EventHandler(form1_Click);
```

This will wipeout all previous event handlers and add only our `form1_Click`

Comment: Please read my question. I know that part. My question is why cant I write just `=` I can write `a = 2` also after all right?

Comment: Nikhil, yes it would, but why not wipe out if the programmer "requires" it? That's my question. You have not read my question. I used the term "override" for your "wipeout" already

Answer (score 2):

Because when you define an [`event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), with the `event SomeHandler SomeEvent` syntax, it default-defines [`add` and `remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713648.aspx) for you. The point here is that the *only* way you publicly interact with an `event` is through `add` and `remove` (accessed by `+=` and `-=`, respectively). The language does not allow a "reset all" action, which is why `=` is not allowed.

To address the more underlying question of a "design choice" for this...I suppose the driving force is that the *contract* of an `event` -- a multicast model where subscribers are free to add and remove their subscriptions. Allowing anyone to unsubscribe all subscribers would go against that contract and allowing only one subscriber *isn't* the contract.

**Addendum:**
It looks like what you're looking for is the ability to expose the delegate directly, which can be done if you just rely on .NET's multicast delegate syntax. It looks a lot like the `event` syntax, but allows for clearing with `=` and is even smart enough to understand `+=` on a `null` `delegate` (see [output](http://ideone.com/xdBG6)):

```
public delegate void F(int x);

public static void Main()
{
    F f = null;
    f += x => System.Console.WriteLine("First: {0}", x);
    f += x => System.Console.WriteLine("Second: {0}", x);
    f(5);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the long form of `event` with your `add`/`remove` hitting an internal list and provide a method that allows for clearing that list.

Comment: And why? That's my question. Naturally I can only think of one reason that is "preventing accidental reseting", but that's upto the programmer right? Reseting can be a desired feature.

Comment: The same reason you mark fields as `private` or separate interface from implementation -- the reset operation is not allowed on an `event` because that is not the contract of it.

Comment: Thanks travis, I am clear now. Yours and @Konstantin's answer made the idea clear for me, but unfortunately only one answer can be marked..

Comment: Well, hopefully the `delegate`-only solution I suggest will work if you're really looking for the `=` syntax. If not, I hope somebody finds my answer helpful :-)

Comment: Travis, thanks for the code. I wasn't looking for a way, but I was knowing the design choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can have none, one or a lot of them, so you add one (subscribe) using `+=` or otherwise remove (unsubscribe) with the oposite `-=`

```
form1.Click += new EventHandler(form1_Click); 
// click here will execute form1_Click
form1.Click += new EventHandler(form1_Click2);
// click here will execute form1_Click1 AND form1_Click2
form1.Click -= new EventHandler(form1_Click1);
// click here will JUST execute form1_Click2
```

Now, enforcing the use of += will be preventing the developer from shooting her own foot. I mean, making able to call form1.Click = ... from any other class will enable one user to clear other attached delegates unintentionally. That's why it's enforced by default.

Comment: But shouldn't that be upto the programmer? I mean clearing off existing eventhandlers can be useful/desired (unlike shooting ur own foot! :) )

Comment: @nawfal I definitively not agree with you. Imagine a team were a couple of developers are working with a common DLL and are attaching an event handler. One of them, the experienced, use += and that's great, but the other -not experienced- one totally forgot (or didn't even know) and just write equal sign, breaking completely the other's one commit. Now, imagine there are no 2 of them but a couple of developer teams. IMHO Little things like this cause bugs very hard to track. Dont you think?

Comment: I wouldnt agree. I would say it's because of the ignorance of developer. At least that can be solved by enlightening developers. But what can you do to override the original handler in the DLL when name is unkown? Thats unsolvable. Would you call it "misused" if it is like this: `myClass.IntProperty = 24` when it will override the existing int value of the variable. The point is that's desired.